# Making Components Available to Nested Modules

Tags: angular, typescript

So right now I have a set up that looks like this:

- App Module

  - A Large Module

    - Another Large Module

      - A Component

`A Component` does NOT have access to components loaded in `A Large Module`, even though those components are defined as both declarations *and* exports of `A Large Module`.

Is there any way that I can give the nested module `Another Large Module` access to the component imports of `A Large Module` so that it's child components will have access to those components? Or do these need to be declared inside `Another Large Module` in order for it's child components to have access to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import things in the module if the components declared in it use those things. You can create a feature module that imports/exports/declares set of components and use it in your other modules.

```
- App Module
   - FeatureA Module
   - FeatureB Module
   - Large Module (import FeatureA Module)
       - Component [can use components from FeatureA; 
                    can't use components from FeatureB]
       - Another Large Module (import FeatureA Module, FeatureB Module)
           - Component [can use components from FeatureA and FeatureB]
```

If your `Large Module` and `Another Large Module` are lazy loaded, you will have `FeatureA module` in both files/packages, but few extra kilobytes won't hurt. One extra benefit is reusability, you can use feature modules in other projects:

```
- Different App Module
   - FeatureA Module
   - FeatureB Module
   - Different Large Module (import FeatureA Module)
       - Component [can use components from FeatureA; 
                    can't use components from FeatureB]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **share** components between modules, the easiest way is to create a shared.module.ts :

```
const SHARED_COMPONENTS = [];

const SHARED_MODULES = [];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...SHARED_COMPONENTS
  ],
  imports: [
    ...SHARED_MODULES
  ],
  exports: [
    ...SHARED_COMPONENTS,
    ...SHARED_MODULES
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**notice the 'exports' key** it allows you to import your `SharedModule` wherever you need it in your hierarchy and use the shared components from everywhere.

Comment: So you are saying that a module above the level of `A Large Module` in my example would need to import all of the modules and components that need to be shared?

Comment: Yep. You'll probably end up importing `SharedModule` everywhere in your app. But it's no big deal. It's loaded once and then you reuse them.

Comment: If you want to only import few, you can create a shared module for every big part of your app. But it'll mostly end up in a big mess and I'd recommend you to have only one shared module ;)

Comment: Ok, so if I do this, I run into another problem. `Another Large Module` would have to be part of the `share.module.ts` files imports, and doing so results in the error `Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'MyModule'` Is there a way around this?